# Find $f(x^2)$ of $f(x)$

Tags: functions

How can I find $f(x^2)$ of $f(x)$?

For example: I take the function $f(x)=a$ where a is an algebraic expression like $\sin x$, $3x^3$, etc.

Now, *is it possible to find $f(x^2)$ of $f(x)=a$?*

If it is possible *how do you do that?*

---

My try: If I assume $f(x)=\sin x$ then $f(x^2)=\sin(x^2)$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes. $ { } { }$

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Where you have $x$,you substitute it with $x^2$.